# Using Environment Variables for connecting to RDS mysql database from php YII application running on docker container

Tags: docker, yii, environment-variables, amazon-ecs

I am running few docker container on aws ecs, All running on php Yii application.

the apps needs to connect to AWS RDS database. currently the databasename, host,username and password is hardcoded in the file "main-local.php"

```
  'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=dbinstancename.xxxxx.region.rds.amazonaws.com;dbname=xxxxxxx',
        'username' => 'xxxxxxxx',
        'password' => 'xxxxxxxx',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
```

I know its not best practice to hardcode the database details in the docker container.  I can pass environment variables into the docker at run time such that "DB_HOST","DB_NAME", "DB_USER","DB_PASSWORD" with the corresponding values.  I can see the same details inside the docker container typing the command "env"

How can this be used in the main-local.php? can we directly substitute the db details in the code with the env variables? Is this something to be done from the developers end?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

Answer (score 0):

To add env support you may use this extension https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

Simply install it

```sh
composer.phar require vlucas/phpdotenv
```

Create `.env` file. It should be in `.gitignore` and not accessed from web. If you are using basic or advanced templates put it with `yii.bat` into the project root. Also you may create `.env.example` with empty variables.

```
YII_DEBUG=1
YII_TRACE_LEVEL=3
YII_ENV=dev
```

Then add it to your index.php like this

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/protected/vendor/autoload.php';

$factory = new Dotenv\Environment\DotenvFactory([
    new Dotenv\Environment\Adapter\EnvConstAdapter(),
]);
// Specify path to directory with .env file here (for advanced you should up twice)
\Dotenv\Dotenv::create(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '/../', null, $factory)->load();

defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', (bool) $_ENV['YII_DEBUG']);
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL', $_ENV['YII_TRACE_LEVEL']);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', $_ENV['YII_ENV']);
```

I recommend to use only EnvConstAdapter. Cause `$_SERVER` variable get logged and `getenv()` some time has empty values on concurrency requests.

Small improvement for `bool`, `null` and empty strings. Add this before `$factory` instantiation and use `env()` instead `$_ENV`.

```
if (!function_exists('env')) {
    /**
     * Gets the value of an environment variable.
     * @param string $key
     * @param mixed $default
     * @return mixed
     */
    function env($key, $default = null)
    {
        if (!isset($_ENV[$key])) {
            return $default;
        }

        $value = $_ENV[$key];

        switch ($value) {
            case 'true':
            case '(true)':
                return true;
            case 'false':
            case '(false)':
                return false;
            case 'empty':
            case '(empty)':
                return '';
            case 'null':
            case '(null)':
                return null;
            default:
                return $value;
        }
    }
}
```